# What is a proper way to execute ruby script from xcode build phase script?

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, release-management, xcodeproj

I wrote some ruby script, that uses CocoaPods/Xcodeproj to edit xcode project file.

This script executes from xcode build phase script:

```
ruby script.rb someProj.xcodeproj
```

Inside ruby script, there is a 'require' for xcodeproj:

```
require 'xcodeproj'
```

When I invoke this script manually from terminal, everything is ok.

But when it invokes from xcode build phase, ruby throws exception:

```
cannot load such a file xcodeproj (something like that)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build phase -> Shell: change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash -l`
Bash login is required, in order to load ruby variables/paths/etc.